# How to open a file in D drive through command prompt

Tags: command, command-prompt

Path of the folder: **D:\Brian\adrk_v1_0** ; this folder has a file called '**filename**' I wish to open the file, 'filename' using the command prompt.

I tried doing it, by writing the following

```
C:\Users\Anshuman

C:\Users\Anshuman> cd /d D:Brian\adrk_v1_0

D:\Brian\adrk_v1_0>
```

But when I try to open the 'makefile' this happens:

```
 Directory of D:\Brian\adrk_v1_0

03-10-2021  11:13    <DIR>          .
03-10-2021  11:13    <DIR>          ..
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          Const
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          Energy
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          Form
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          GMICPP
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          Group
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          Input
14-12-2002  04:13             1,046 i_data.txt
11-12-2002  03:50             3,294 makefile
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          Master
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          Output
14-12-2002  04:20               223 o_rmv.dat
14-12-2002  04:20             3,718 o_sdf.dat
14-12-2002  04:20               223 o_sum.dat
14-12-2002  04:20               151 o_vac.dat
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          PD
14-12-2002  06:16             2,394 readme.txt
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          SDF
13-12-2002  22:16    <DIR>          Vector
               7 File(s)         11,049 bytes
              13 Dir(s)  579,931,025,408 bytes free

D:\Brian\adrk_v1_0>makefile
'makefile' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried changing the path to C: System 32 in the environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should specify a texteditor, for Example:

```
notepad makefile
```

Comment: I have to compile this makefile; as mentioned in the instructions. How to compile this makefile using the command prompt?

 - compile the program, running "makefile" in the command prompt;
 - gmicpp.exe will be created;